# Finding the determinant of a $3 \times 3$ matrix via Laplace Expansion

Tags: matrices, laplace-expansion

I have a matrix here where I need to calculate the determinant using Laplace expansion.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0 & 1\\19 & 1 & -3\\7 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So I did the simple *diagonal & antidiagonal* way to calculate and get

$$
\begin{align*}
|A| &= 0 + 0 + 19-7-0-(-12) \\&=24
\end{align*}$$

Right now, I have to show that, by Laplace expansion, and am having a mistake:

$$
\begin{align*}
|A| &= 
4\begin{vmatrix}1 & -3\\1 & 0\end{vmatrix}+
0\begin{vmatrix}19 & -3\\7 & 0\end{vmatrix}+
1\begin{vmatrix}19 & 1\\7 & 1\end{vmatrix}\\
&= 4(-3) + 0 + 1(12)\\
&= 0
\end{align*}$$

Could someone help and spot my errors here?

UPDATE:
The 2nd last row should be $3$, not $-3$, as shown in the answer.

Comment: it should be $4 \cdot (-(-3))$ since $$\begin{vmatrix} a & b\\c&d\\\end{vmatrix}=ad-bc$$

Comment: On the second last line, you computed the determinant as -3 instead of 3.

Comment: And (though it doesn't matter here), the middle term should be $\color {red}- 0\cdot\Bigl|{19\atop 7}\ {-3\atop 0}\Bigr|$.

Comment: @DavidMitra can I say that the $+/-$ depends on the relative position of the particular element (scalar outside)? From top-left, take positions down & right, add up all the positions and take $-1$ raised to that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left|\begin{array}{cc}1 & -3\\1 & 0\end{array}\right|=(1\cdot 0)-(1\cdot-3)=0-(-3)=3$$